# decode hashing with r

Tags: r, hash

I have a hashing problem in R: I need to decode the following example:

```
var1 <- c("ldkssxwpmemidmecebumciepifcamkci", "lxidpiddsbxsbosboudacockeimpuepw", 

          "kamkkxfxxuwbdslkwifmmcsiusiuosws", "kamkkxfxxuwbdslkwifmmcsiusiuosws",

          "kamkkxfxxuwbdslkwifmmcsiusiuosws", "lxidpiddsbxsbosboudacockeimpuepw",

          "",                                 "kamkkxfxxuwbdslkwifmmcsiusiuosws")
```

So, the commercial interpretation of the variable is lost as a result of the hashing, but it may still have predictive power. So, I need to give a sense of these hashing.

Is there a way to decode it in R, in order to give them a numerica value or string value?
Please, not that there is also empty value.

Comment: What you seem to be after is something called the _hash code_.  This is basically the numerical value used to bucket each entry in the actual hashmap.

Comment: convert them to `factor` ? `factor(var1)` ?

Comment: Are you showing us the keys or the values?  Note that the keys are about as unique as you can get here; two different keys might share the same hash code.

Comment: Is this GDPR impact? Consider just not hashing complete variable but psuedo-anonymize. Say retain phone number's first N digit which is of predictive value than hashing complete phone number. With right N identifying corresponding user should not be possible.

Comment: what do you mean with "key"?

Comment: if i convertvar1 as factor I have up to 9000 unique hash, so I have a pattern, but how can I use it to assign the same value to the same group of hash?